# Unable to customize breadcrumbs on Site Contents OOTB page

Tags: office-365, breadcrumb

I have a requirement where I need to display the breadcrumbs in the following format:

`HOME > SITE CONTENTS`

In order to implement this I added the following block of code to the master page:

```
<asp:SiteMapPath runat="server" SiteMapProvider="SPContentMapProvider" RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="false" NodeStyle-CssClass="breadcrumbNode" 
                                CurrentNodeStyle-CssClass="breadcrumbCurrentNode" RootNodeStyle-CssClass="breadcrumbRootNode" HideInteriorRootNodes="true" SkipLinkText=""/>
```

This is working great on all the page of the site except for the `viewlsts.aspx` which is the `Site Contents` page. It displays the breadcrumbs in a tree like format like

`-Root Site Name`

```
   . SiteContents
```

Note that this is the Team site on which I am working.
I am unable to render the bread crumbs in the format that has been described earlier.

How can this be fixed? Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

> It's a style issue

You will need to apply the same styles as the other pages for the breadcrumbs.

Your best bet would be include the style on the master page.